# Checking for ambiguities in decision tree

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using sklearn's decision tree to replace a messy and unmantainable implementation of business rules as a long if-elif-else chain. I validate the tree using thousands of test cases for all labels, but sometimes the table with rules I'm using as training data have errors and some tests fail randomly.

I need a way to validate the tree, beyond the test cases for the outcomes. Is it correct to assume that if all leaf nodes have a gini = 0.0, there will be no random variation in classification across trees generated with a different random seed? If I need to enforce that on my application, is it reasonable to check for that when updating the training data?

Notice that my case is not a typical classification problem, since I already have the decision tree implemented in code, and I want to use an algorithm to generate an equivalent tree from carefully tailored data, rather than a real world data sample, simply because in my case maintaining the data set with business rules is easier than maintaining the code.

So, in my data set the features will ideally cover all the possible range of values and give one unambiguous label for that. For instance, while a real world training set might be something like:

```
features = [[1], [1.1], [2], [2.3]]
labels = ['sativa', 'sativa', 'indica', 'indica']
```

And an algorithm can come up randomly with a tree1 like:

```
if feature < 1.75:
    return 'sativa'
else:
    return 'indica'
```

And a tree2 like:

```
if feature < 1.55:
    return 'sativa'
else:
    return 'indica'
```

However, my training set wouldn't have the gaps where randomness occurs. It would be like:

```
features = [[1], [1.9], [2], [2.3]]
labels = ['sativa', 'sativa', 'indica', 'indica']
```

So, regardless of the initial random state, the tree would always be (obviously, ignoring differences below 0.1):

```
if feature < 1.95:
    return 'sativa'
else:
    return 'indica'
```

My problem is precisely that I need to validate if the training set has an error and there's a gap of values where random variation can occur, or if the same set of features is being assigned to different labels. Fixing the random state doesn't solve that problem, it only guarantees the same data will always generate the same tree.

So, is there any way to determine if this happens with a tree, other than validating the data for those problems before generating the tree, or running a comprehensive testing a number of times big enough to rule out the random variation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the rules of labeling, and know the possible range of the features, you can achieve your objective.

### Let's visualize this with examples

### The Gini indice

What the gini indice means? It tries to fit the training set in the tree you've just made, and tells how wrong their items would be labeled. So, in Tree1 and Tree2 you have gini = 0, because every example from the training set would be rightfully labeled.

Tree1 and Tree2 have the same training set, and gini = 0.0. But, if we try to label x=[1.7], we will get different results.

### Solution

Since you have knowledge of the rules that binds the set of features with its respective labeling, it is, possible to assure that given a training set, it will always generate a tree that outputs the right outcome, for any possible feature, if:

- The features that are continous values are inside a range, Ex. [2,30]
- You can have a precision threshold, Ex. the example above variates at least in 0.1 steps
- You can generate examples for every combination possible
- Your Tree have gini = 0.0

(basically, we are telling that, since gini = 0.0, then if you give a input that was in the training set it will correctly be labeled. No giant leaped conclusions here).

So, if:

```
   feature1 one of numpy.linspace(1,2,11) = [1., 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, ..., 2]
   feature2 one of True or False
```

And:

```
    Your examples have all the possible linear combinations 
    You have sum(all gini nodes) = 0
    The future examples are inside the condition boundaries of the training set
```

Then you can be certain that:

```
    You covered all possible examples
    All possible examples are labeled correctly
```

In this way, random trees initialized randomly will have the same output. They could differ only in examples that are outside the range of the training set, or ones that have values with values that don't follow the threshold rule.

Guess you already did that, but it would be a good idea to create a training set using test coverage tools, to ensure that all possible examples are being created.

### About the necessity of using all possible values in continuous values

I had been extra careful when i stated that you need to have all the possible values for continuous values, like [1.0, 1.1, 1.2, ... 1.9, 2.0]. If the feature are used in only one node, than you could use only the boundaries values (1.9 and 2.0 in the example). But, if your if-elses are more complicated, we could have some complex scenarios that are unpredictable. After a node that evaluates feature f1, we could have later on the left-generated node a condition like (if f2 > 5), and a (if f2 < 3) in the right node, or something like that. And you could get wrong outcomes.

If your combinations get too big, than it may be a good idea to binarize the features. If you have a continuous feature like:

```
    if f1 > 3: f1 = 'many'
    if 3 <= f1 < 0 = 'little'
```

You transform it into (1 0) and (0 1), using DictVectorizer object.

Althoug you are increasing the number of dimensions, your decision tree would only create one node for the two features. If its only checks if the first is true, the second is redundant, because they are mutually exclusive.

This is also a solution if you don't have boundaries for your data. If you have a x feature that has no range, you can binarize it like (x < 0, 0<= x < 5, 5 <= x), transforming a continuous value into (1 0 0), (0 1 0) or (0 0 1), allowing you to evaluate all possible combinations.

In that way you can radically reduce the size of the set of the combinations.

Hope that`s it.
Cheers!

Comment: I don't get it. If a random item has 0% change of being labeled wrong when that node has a gini = 0.0, then how it doesn't say anything about the randomness of the result? What I need is that for a given input, the same tree always returns the same result, but when the gini of sibling leaf nodes is different from zero, some results get randomly assigned to one or the other, and that is undesirable in my application.

Comment: I edited my answer. See if it is more clear now :)
It seems you are confusing the randomness of the fitting process with ranomness in the predict process.

Comment: Nope, I get that, but that's not what I meant. I edited the question to clarify the problem, based on your example.

Comment: It's your question answered now?

Comment: Almost there. Are you saying the training data must have all possible combinations?

Comment: Made a edit on how to use values that has no boundaries.
But basically that`s what i`m saying. You want to be sure of a very difficult thing (that your classificator will never be wrong).

That's usually off-the-table, but, since you are Omniscient about the classification rules, the only way i see you beeing so sure is getting a gini = 0 for all leaves, and training it with all possible combinations. Try to binarize data, and reduce the number of possible combinations.

Comment: Having all examples in the training set, and having gini = 0 it`s a text book example of a exhaustive testing.

There are other ways to be confident (but not be sure) about the quality of the classifier. You can make a program that counts the frequency of combinations in real life, and test only the most frequent ones. That can be measured objectively, and you can have a "real" range of confidence (my guess is that if you count the most frequent ones, you can get a possible margin of error < 10^-5, or something like that).

Another way of getting a great confidence is cross validating it.

Comment: Cross validating with a large set will give a great confidence. A confidence good enough to believe that the classifier is "correct". But again, not mathematically sure.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I don't want to be sure that the classifier will never be wrong. I want to be sure the hand-made training data doesn't have conflicting or missing data that will generate different random trees that can lead to random results. I thought having tests for all combinations and gini = 0 in all leaf nodes was enough to guarantee that, and I wouldn't have to validate the data before generating the tree. You're saying it's not, that I have to validate the data. That answers the question. Thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: Generating all combinations for training defeats the purpose, since I'd have to write the exact same code I'm trying to replace to generate the data. :)

Comment: I hoped for a fully automated way to validate that, but I think I will use the fixed random state, guarantee gini = 0 and validate the tree chart manually. As of now, my trees are complex, but it's still reasonable to do that.